# What is a keyboard "without frame"?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I keep hearing "without frame" when trying to find a notebook replacement keyboard. Is it dysfunctional, or does it only mean it doesn't come with the common cover of a desktop keyboard and it's safe to use in a laptop as a replacement as-is?

--

EDIT:

e.g. this: [http://www.amazon.com/HQRP-Keyboard-compatible-DV7T-4100-Replacement/dp/B005G2QY4S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005G2QY4S)

I start suspecting it means only a black cover over the keys (between the key gaps) that comes with the laptop. But not sure.

Comment: That's right. The frame is usually just part of the laptop case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without frame is another name for just the keyboard, and only the keyboard.

In most laptops, a keyboard is simply just a keyboard that you can remove in one go and replace with another unit.

Typically, the majority of keyboards are like this.

I have never heard of this name before, however, from replacing keyboards, it makes perfect sense to me. There are an increasing amount of keyboards where the keys are "sunk"/separated and these sometimes have a cover over the top that pops out, and again, sometimes it is an all in one unit.

So, to me, without frame simply means that if your laptop's keyboard contains an optional part such as a frame that goes over it, you will not get this part included with the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspect as well, but it is a confusing description. By replacing keyboards myself it's just common sense that it won't come with the whole covers of the PC itself. So, I wasn't sure if it means something else.

Comment: It was a cover above the keys and also a plastic undercover.

Comment: I'll add my 5 cents.. If you are buying a keyboard "without frame" and at the same time you're able to get the same "with frame" - it is better to take the second one. It can be a real pain to remove the old frame from the old keyboard. Yesterday I was installing a new one without frame to my hp g7, and it took about 15 minutes to remove an old frame + I've made a couple of cracks on it, not critical, but unpleasant. The frame itself is used not only to cover the space between keys, but it is also used to fix the keyboard inside the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Some laptop keyboard have a plastic frame on it. The frame itself is a plastic structure between the keycaps. For example, the HP DV6-6000 laptop keyboard has a plastic frame. But not all laptop keyboard have frames for example the ACER ASPIRE 5810T does not .

One main problem is that, if you need to replace your old laptop keyboard, like for HP DV6-6000, but you only have a DV6-6000 keyboard without a frame(some models use a keyboard that has no frame), you have to remove the frame on your old keyboard, and then set it on the new keyboard(which has no frame). Only in this way you can replace it.

User may prefer those keyboards with frame, since it may take less time to replace the keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to superuser - under normal circumstances, I'd spam flag this, but this is one of the few cases where an answer goes against out. Here's our [rules](http://superuser.com/a/645894/10165) for more details. I've edited it to make sure its entirely ok - you can probably add a link to your company in your profile, and mention "I work for X" when answering related questions. You'll also want to answer other questions as well.